# How to close div (modal) clicking outside. Pinterest and Facebook way

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, pinterest

The classic way to is to do a modal is a div with the content (dialog) and a div with z-index lower (overlay)
Then, I can bind the click event on the overlay and hide de content dialog.

```
<div class="dialog">...</div>
<div class="overlay" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)">
```

But I have noticed that Pinterest and Facebook combines it to one div.

```
<div class="overlay" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);position: fixed; z-index: 9999;top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;">
      <div class="dialog" style="position: static;"></div>
</div>
```

But in this approach, how can I bind the click event to close de dialog only in the overlay that not have the dialog?

http://jsfiddle.net/mCupS/9/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By doing something like this:

```
$('.modal').click(function(){
     $('.modal, .inner').hide(); 
});                                    
$('.inner').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});              
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mCupS/10/

[`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) : Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: `stopPropagation()` is strongly discouraged... https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Answer (score 2):

`stopPropagation` will stop the event propagation to parent controls and you will not get model click event:

```
$('.modal ').click(function(){
    alert("a");
});

$('.inner').click(function(e){
    alert("b");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Edit**, a better way to achieve the above.

There could be a better way as pointed in comments then above suggested solution as discussed in [The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/). By this way you can ensure that the inner item is not being click to hide.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mCupS/177/)

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.inner').length) {
    $('.modal .inner').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()` is strongly discouraged... https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: Thanks @user664833.